# How to compare a user input variable modified with strings in Python elseif?

Tags: if-statement, python-3.5

Below is the code I am trying to run. I need the code to display access granted if the password is equal to name or `password=name123`. However I cannot get it to work.

Please help as I am a newbee on Python

```
print ('Please enter your username')
name = input()
print ('Please enter your password')
password = input ()
if name == password:
print ('Hello ' + str(name) + ' , Access Granted')
elif password == str(str("name") + '123'):
print ('Hello ' + str(name) + ' , Access Granted')
else:
print ( 'Sorry Access Denied')
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear from the code and your explanation that you want `asd` and `asd123` to be granted access, or you want `asd` and `name123` to get access, but i assume the first.

The problem is that you were evaluating 'name' as a string of letters instead of the input variable `name` as a string.

This should do it:

```
name = input('Please enter your username\n')
password = input('Please enter your password\n')
if name == password:
    print ('Hello ' + str(name) + ' , Access Granted')
elif password == str(name) + '123':
    print ('Hello ' + str(name) + ' , Access Granted')
else:
    print ( 'Sorry Access Denied')
```